Can the server of a NextJs app in production access a database which is available only on localhost?
I'm trying to create a secure environment for my deployed app and do not want the database to be accessible publicly. Which is why I want the database (pocketbase) to be only on localhost and accessed only through the server actions of NextJs during usage.
Doing this however leads to NextJs being unable to access the db port on localhost. Shouldn't this be possible since the server is on the same computer as the database and should have access to the local host ?
Am I missing something ?
